# How to get keys from json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Cocktail 1",
        "ingredients": {
            "rum": 12,
            "coke": 48
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Cocktail 2",
        "ingredients": {
            "gin": 24,
            "tonic": 60
        }
    }]
```

Now I want to get a list of the keys of each "name" object. At the end there should be ths list

```
var mydata[0] = rum
var mydata[1] = coke
var mydata[2] = gin 
var mydata[3] = tonic
```

and save it into an array.

What i have tried

```
var mydata = JSON.parse("jsonstring").ingredients;
```

hope this is understanable?

Comment: What is the issue ? What have you tried and what error you are getting? or you are just looking for help with homework ? ;)

based on your description you are not looking for keys in a json object, you are looking for the value of the key name in an array of objects.

Comment: That's not a list of keys, that's a modified list of one key's values in the array of objects. What do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each data in the array (map)
you want the ingredient part (.ingredients),
extract the keys (Object.keys)
and flatten the array (.flat())

```
array.map(a => a.ingredients).map(a => Object.keys(a)).flat();
```

You may prefer loop style. the only difference is flattening occurs with ... operator.

```
var results = [];
for (let a of array) {
  results.push(...Object.keys(a.ingredients))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My proposition  is :

```js
'use strict'

const array  = [
  {
    "name": "Cocktail 1",
    "ingredients": {
      "rum": 12,
      "coke": 48
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Cocktail 2",
    "ingredients": {
      "gin": 24,
      "tonic": 60
    }
  }
]

const mydata = array.map((val) => {
  return Object.keys(val.ingredients);
}).flat();

console.log(mydata)
// expected output: Array ["rum", "coke", "gin", "tonic"]

// Now you can get :

var mydata[0] = rum
var mydata[1] = coke
var mydata[2] = gin
var mydata[3] = tonic
```

Hope that help you? Thank